# Expected value of exponential distribution with integration by parts (non-textbook way)

Tags: integration, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I try to calculate expected value of exponential distribution with integration by parts without success.
I know that the text book way to do it so that first take lambda out of the integral and then do the integration by parts.
What if I would like to calculate it directly:
\begin{align} 
E[X]=\int_{0}^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx
\end{align}
And now
\begin{align} 
f(x)=x, \quad f'(x)=dx
\end{align}
and
\begin{align} 
g'(x)=-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx, \quad g(x)= e^{-\lambda x}
\end{align}
So I would like to start with
\begin{align} 
E[X]=-\int_{0}^\infty x (-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}) dx.
\end{align}
Is this possible and if not why not?

Comment: I mean sure, but its exactly what you started with. You haven't made any real progress.

Comment: Choose $u(x)=x$ and $v^{'}(x)=-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. Then it works. Advice: Take care of the signs (+,-).

Comment: I think this is exactly what I try to do and the question is how it works.

Comment: @Parallax Give a reply whether you succeeded or not.

Comment: I didn't. I will add my calculations to my question.

Comment: Yes, I had it now right, thank you.

Comment: @Parallax That pleases me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is much easier to use the fact (which follows from Tonelli's theorem) that for a non-negative random variable $X$ with finite mean, $\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))\ \mathsf dx$, with $F_X$ being the distribution function of $X$. Hence
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^ \infty e^{-\lambda t}\ \mathsf dt = \frac1\lambda.
$$